# Java send data issue with Firebase Realtime Database using REST API

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the following JAVA code to send some data to Firebase Realtime Database using REST API.

```
public void doWork() {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Sending data: " + record.value() );

            //  https://testiosproject-6054a.firebaseio.com/users.json
         // 1. URL
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://testiosproject-1234a.firebaseio.com/users.json");

                // 2. Open connection
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();              
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // 3. Specify POST method
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.connect();

                // Write data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                osw.write(record.value());
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The following is the data trying to send:

```
Sending data: {"UserID":"101","UserAddress":"XYZ","UserAccount":"987","UserName":"Stella"}
```

But, I am not getting this data received on Firebase Realtime database console. I am not sure what could be the reason for this issue?

I tried Postman client and tried the same URL and data, it works fine.

Could someone guide me to fix this issue?

Comment: are you getting response and only not able to store data on firebase.?

Comment: How to check response? I didn't get that.

Comment: You say, that this is the data `Received message: {"UserID":"101","UserAddress":"XYZ","UserAccount":"987","UserName":"Stella"}` that you are trying to send. How are you trying to send this data? Please share the code.

Comment: Sending data code is already in the question right - osw.write(record.value());

Comment: I fixed it by adding osw.write(record.value().toString());

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can answer your own question. :)

Comment: Why are you trying to handle the HTTP protocol at such a low level? Perhaps using something like CXF's [WebClient](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html) class would remove some of the boilerplate code. Moreover, using CXF would allow you to easily turn on/off logging interceptors to help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a lib that abstracts some of these things such as CXF (for the actual HTTP stuff) and Jackson (for JSON handling). The code would be made much simpler:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://testiosproject-1234a.firebaseio.com");
client.path("users.json");
client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response r = client.post(record);
MyResponseClassIfAny b = r.readEntity(MyResponseClassIfAny .class);
```

Adapted from [CXF Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-CXFWebClientAPI).

Note that most of the WebClient setup code could (and probably should) be done outside the fr loop since it never changes.

Comment: Note that, based on Firebase's [POST documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-post), it does return a value, whether or not you want/need it is up to you.